# ReactiveUI.Routing dependency on Splat

Tags: mvvm, reactiveui, splat

The ReactiveUI.Routing requires us to register the views in Splat container (Locator.CurrentMutable). If I don’t register it  with Splat it is not working.
If we are using some other IOC container or service locator like Ninject, is tere a way to provide our own container to ReactiveUI.Routing? Or still we should register the views in Splat?

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 ways to do that, you can fully replace the splat locator default implementation by NInject, [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactivexaml/TME1hUI62TM/cEidpNvjDo0J)'s a post of someone who did that.

You can also set the [ViewLocator](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/Xaml/RoutedViewHost.cs#L57) property on your RouteViewHost (before its activation), which won't go to Splat once it's set.

Comment: Thanks Gluck,  I'll try the option 1. I am using Xamarin.Forms. ViewLocator property seems to be not available in RouteViewHost class

Answer (score 0):

Here I am, 7 years late, but there is a library out there now called [Splat.Ninject](https://github.com/reactiveui/splat/tree/main/src/Splat.Ninject) which does this nice and easy. Here's some demo code with it based on the [ReactiveUI WPF routing library](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/blob/main/wpf/ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing).

### AppBootstrapper:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : ReactiveObject, IScreen
{
    public RoutingState Router { get; }
    public IKernel Kernel { get; }

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Kernel = new PrimaryKernel(this);
        Kernel.UseNinjectDependencyResolver();   // Switch from splat to Ninject
        Router = Kernel.Get<RoutingState>();
    }
}
```

### PrimaryKernel.cs

```
public class PrimaryKernel : StandardKernel
{
    private AppBootstrapper bootstrapper;
    public PrimaryKernel(AppBootstrapper bootstrapper) {
        this.bootstrapper = bootstrapper;
        LoadDependencies();
    }
    public void LoadDependencies()
    {
        // Alternatively have modules here

        // Navigation binding
        Bind<RoutingState>().ToMethod(c => new RoutingState()).InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IScreen>().ToMethod(c => bootstrapper).InSingletonScope();

        // Bind viewmodels
        Bind<IFirstViewModel>().To<FirstViewModel>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<ISecondViewModel>().To<SecondViewModel>().InSingletonScope();

        // Bind views
        Bind<IViewFor<IFirstViewModel>>().To<FirstView>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IViewFor<ISecondViewModel>>().To<SecondView>().InSingletonScope();

    }
}
```

And then I changed things so my MainWindow.xaml.cs was the one that Routed to the first view. To me this made more sense than having the AppBootstrapper do it.

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppBootstrapper bootstrapper = new AppBootstrapper();
        DataContext = bootstrapper;
        var Kernel = bootstrapper.Kernel;
        Kernel.Get<IScreen>().Router.Navigate.Execute(Kernel.Get<IFirstViewModel>()); // Show the first window.
    }
}
```

The views and viewmodels haven't changed much from the example on Github I linked earlier, but I changed the views'  ViewModel DependencyProperties to constructor params so Ninject can take care of them. Here's an example of FirstView, you can figure out the rest.

### FirstView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class FirstView : IViewFor<IFirstViewModel>
{
    public FirstView(IFirstViewModel viewmodel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewmodel;
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            d(this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel).BindTo(this, x => x.DataContext));
            d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.NavigateToSecond, view => view.navigateButton));
        });
    }

    public IFirstViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (IFirstViewModel)value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it's probably better to init the appbootstrapper from the ninject kernel. Just call this.UseNinjectDependencyResolver() in the constructor.